# Implementing soft delete with @Filter and lazy loaded associations

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, soft-delete

I am implementing soft delete with Hibernate. Each entity that supports soft-deleting has an attribute for it.

```
@Column(name = "DELETED")
private boolean deleted;
```

I have created @FilterDef in package-info.java for package with domain objects.

```
@FilterDef(name = "deletedFilter",
    parameters = @ParamDef(name = "includeDeleted", type = Boolean.class),
    defaultCondition = ":includeDeleted = true OR DELETED = false"
)
```

applied it to all DeleteAware entities

```
@Filter(name = "deletedFilter")
public class CustomerGroup
```

and enabled in when using in queries

```
Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
session.enableFilter("deletedFilter")
       .setParameter("includeDeleted", fp.isDeleted());
```

Filter is applied and works correctly for primary entity (for example when I query customers I can see that additional where condition is always applied as needed).

Problem is with filter of association. Let's say Customer entity has collection of CustomerGroup.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "CUSTOMER_CUSTOMER_GROUP",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID"))
private Set<CustomerGroup> groups;
```

However when I query for Customer, groups collection contains deleted entities. I have turned on sql logging and I can see that condition is not applied for lazy query. However if I change

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

to

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

it works.

Both entities are annotated with @Filter. I have also tried applying @Filter annotation to collection itself success without. For initial testing I have also ensured that filters are not disabled and includeDeleted parameter is always false.

@Where annotation on entities works like a charm, but cannot be disabled (99% percent of queries we want to filter out deleted objects but there is that pesky 1% where we need deleted ones).

We are using Hibernate 6.1.13 provided in WildFly 27 application server. Looks like filters are not applied when relation is lazy loaded. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try adding `@Filter(name = "deletedFilter")` to this `groups` field yet?

Comment: Yes, without success.

Comment: If you think this is a bug, you should create a reproducer (https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-6/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) and report the problem on the issue tracker (https://hibernate.atlassian.net). By the way, here is a test from the Hibernate testsuite that actually exercises this and it appears to work: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/documentation/src/test/java/org/hibernate/userguide/pc/FilterTest.java#L224